# Why is my 'prev' method for my doubly-linked lists acting like this?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program in Java that implements the doubly linked list.

I've initialized my methods involving 'prev' (previous node) by:

```
public IntDNode getPrev() {
    return prev;
}
```

My program hasn't been working properly, so I wrote a program that tested the values of prev which is:

```
public int tester() {

    IntDNode t = head;
    t = t.getNext();
    t = t.getPrev();

    return t.getValue();
}
```

I added 5 elements to my array (0 1 2 3 4 5)

Without t=t.getPrev(), my value is 1.
With t=t.getPrev(), my value is 2 when it should be 0.

I can't figure out if I've initialized my methods incorrectly somewhere or if I'm not assigning values correctly.

Comment: What does your constructor look like?

Comment: The constructor for both getPrev and get Next are in the form of:
    public IntDNode getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }

switching the words "prev" and "next" for getNext().  There is nothing  explicit in my code that makes getPrev go to getNext, since I just return the value of "prev"

Comment: I meant your *constructor*. How do you initially set the value of `prev` and `next`? You have a `public IntDNode() {}` of some kind, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  I have:


    public class IntDNode() {
        val = 0;
        prev = null;
        next = null;
    }

Comment: Sorry, could you post your entire `IntDNode` class? I can't find anything wrong in what you've given so far.